# POP3/IMAP direct implementation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, imap, pop3

Is there any way, how to communicate with POP3/IMAP server.

For example for build a pure-JavaScript e-mail notifier?

I've found this:
ftp://ftp.activexperts-labs.com/samples/aemail/HTML/POP3/index.htm

Unfortunately it uses the ActiveX objects, which really doesn't work in many modern browsers.

It would be nice to have ability to send a packet through any protocol (= not only HTTP/S) in HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with purely browser-based Javascript: there are is no direct socket connection support in browser Javascript. You can use special extensions in things like Firefox's Extension environment to do pure socket connections, but not in a standard browser JS file.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the Same Origin Policy implemented in all recent browsers would slap you in the face for this. I'd simply add a server-side layer to mediate between JSON/AJAX and POP3/IMAP - roughly what gmail does.

Comment: That's a solution, but this requires necessary steps from the mailbox-provider or (in worst case) on my own server (as it could be used as a "proxy"). I am looking for solution, which (in best case) would requires no steps on the server side.

Comment: Well, in that case you're probably down to non-javascript plugins to make it work; and even then, you may run into the browser's security measures.